# Build a dependency graph between objects

Tags: c++, build

I am working on a small in-house build tool and I want to allow it to parallelize. For that to work properly, I would like to build up a queue based on dependencies.

I.e.:

```
foo.c -> foo.o
bar.c -> bar.o
baz.c -> baz.o
foo.o bar.o baz.o -> app.exe
```

On a single-threaded queue executor, I would just iterate through each of the steps and exit upon error (i.e. the compiler encounters a severe error). I would like to achieve parallelism, where a maximum amount of parallel tasks would be given (4, in this case) and the pool would poll from the queue - but could only poll all the steps required to build the dependencies for `app.exe`. Only when those are completed, `app.exe` would be allowed to be build.

I figured that this would require some form of dependency graph. Now, since I am visually impaired, I usually shied away from anything that remotely sounded "graphical"... so I probably missed something important in school; my fault there.

Is there a type of graph I could read up on, or even a C/C++ library that can do this for me? This is really the only part that I am lost at, as preparing everything else is really just a string of commands and programm availability checks (is a C compiler available, can the output folder be written to, ...).

Comment: Might be useful https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html

Comment: Make a directed graph based on the dependencies and do a topological sort on it.